# android api 23+, Write file in root external storage

Tags: java, android, linux, filesystems, storage

I can create a folder in the root of a external storage USB/SD but not a file.
Is this a restriction of android or is there something wrong with my permissions.

On creating a file I get a "java.io.IOException: Permission denied" message.

First I check my permissions and they seem fine.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
{
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 3);
}

if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
{
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 2);
}
```

Then I scan for my external device and I found them.
SD -> mnt/media_rw/0123-4567
USB -> mnt/media_rw/B80A-07EC

Both USB and SD have the same behaiour so I will only give a code example of the SD.

```
String folder = "/testfolder/";
String file = "testfile.txt";
```

--

```
check = new File("mnt/media_rw/0123-4567" + file).createNewFile();
```

This will result in a "java.io.IOException: Permission denied"

```
check = new File("mnt/media_rw/0123-4567" + folder).mkdirs();
check = new File("mnt/media_rw/0123-4567" + folder + file).createNewFile();
```

This will result in the creating of a folder with a file inside it.

Don't mind the variable names it's only a example/

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/mnt/media_rw/0123-4567` with a leading slash? You app's working directory is its sandbox, not the root of the file system. Also there are other ways to refer to external storage using Android.

Comment: That's referred to as _removable_ storage, not just external storage in general. You should find several relevant answers here if you search with that term.